# ReactJS need to call function from outside class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, surveyjs

I have some various third party code in which I need to be able to call function from outside

```
//**Import**

import React from 'react'
// .... etc..

//**function I need to have call the function inside react component**

function showDescription(element) {
    // NEED to call function inside component class 
    this.

}

//**Class Component is here and notice state is set, and onClick had bind**

class SectionE extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          visible: false   // setting to true will display the modal dialog box
        }
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

//**This is the What I want to call from outside!**     

    onClick() {
        this.setState({visible: true}); // show modal dialog
    }

//**Mount, calling in here works fine**         

    componentDidMount() {

        //this works as another test
        // this.onClick();
    }   

     render()
    {
        return(

//**Testing calling is works fine (Inside )**

    // manually show dialog   this works
   <button type="button" icon="pi pi-external-link" onClick={this.onClick} className="btn btn-primary" id="btnImportant">Add Important People</button>

//**3rd party primereact modal dialog** 

     <Dialog id="modal" header="Important People for ...." visible={this.state.visible} style={{width: '75vw'}} footer={footer} onHide={this.onHide} maximizable>
                    <ImportantFamily/>
     </Dialog>
     )
    }
}

 export default SectionE;
```

So it is not a child component or parent that i'm trying to call from , but code outside of the class component.  Thus I don't see how `Ref` will even work.

There is a lot more code with SurveyJS 3rd party code that i have outside of react component is biggest reason this code is functions outside.

**What are my options?**

Comment: Breaking up the code like you've done is pretty confusing to look at, it's not clear whether this is all in the same file, or if you're referencing code snippets from different files. Are you able to concatenate those snippets into a single block (and replace the associated headers with comments in the code for example)? It might make it more readable and easier to follow

Comment: ok fixed.   thx @JonWarren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option would be to add a prop to your `SectionE` component and then listen to updates on that prop e.g. where you are adding `SectionE` add a prop called "visible" where you can set that visible variable from outside the SectionE class:

```
<SectionE visible={visible} />
```

Then do something inside your SectionE when it changes:

```
// this is inside your SectionE class:
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.visible !== this.props.visible) {
        this.setState({visible: this.props.visible}); // show/hide modal dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: so when i call SectionE , have it set visible={visible}  ?

Comment: A few issues.  When the parent calls SectionE , visible is not defined so i gather you are setting to add a prop to the parent.   Then also , i call it currently like the following, so can i just add it ?   `<SectionE ref={this.childE} />`  so then it would be `<SectionE ref={this.childE} visible={visible} />`  right?

Comment: got it working with  `<SectionE ref={this.childE} ref={(secEComponent) => {window.secEComponent = secEComponent}} />`    then   `window.secEComponent.onClick();`